# Array memory c# (copied to new reference or using the same?)

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

So I couldn't seem to figure this out. In the following code:

```
int[] array1 = { 86, 66, 76, 92, 95, 88 };
int[] array2 = new int[6];
array2 = array1;
```

When array2 is "copying" the values of array1, is it creating new memory references or is it referencing the same memory index as the values in array1?

Comment: The same reference since an array is a reference type.

Comment: perfect, much appreciated!

Comment: The "new int[6];" assigned to array2 will be immediately discarded when array1 is assigned to array2

Comment: true, but it's fairly irrelevant for this example anyways.

Answer (score 4):

[`Arrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx) are reference types, therefore you are assigning the same reference.

> Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type
>   [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx).

If you want to create a deep copy, you can use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx):

```
int[] array1 = { 86, 66, 76, 92, 95, 88 };
int[] array2 = new int[array1.Length];
Array.Copy(array1, array2, array1.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are of reference type. You can easily check this yourself

```
array2[1] = 2;
Console.WriteLine(array1[1]); // will print out 2
```

When you change one you change the other because both point to (reference) the same memory location.

Answer (score 0):

It is referencing the same array. So if you change a value in array1 it will also be changed in array2.